# How getName() method is used in Object class?

Tags: java

I am a new learner of JAVA Language. In JAVA the Object class is the root class (or) top most Super class in the class hierarchy (every class is a subclass of Object). So every class we create have the 11 methods (as mentioned in JAVA API) of the Object class and we can use them, like the `toString()` method.

But the definition of the `toString()` method uses a method `getName()` which is not defined in Object class. (I know that the `toString()` method uses the `getName()` method because I have used jd-gui to view the source code of the Object.class file installed in my pc.)

If we create a java file

```
class test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      test t = new test();
      System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
/* Don't understand how I am able to use getName() method without extending any other
*class containing *getName() method.*/
  }
}
```

The above gives "test" as the output without error.

Coming to Object class it is the root class so it is not extending any other classes and to do any work it should define its own methods.

My Question is, 
How are the Object class and classes we define able to use this method without defining the `getName()` method in their class?

Are any other classes are extended by besides the Object class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getName()` is a method of the `Class` class, not the `Object` class. `Object` has a [getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method that returns a `Class` instance.

`t.getClass()` returns an instance of `Class<test>`, which has the method [getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).
This allows you to call `t.getClass().getName()`.

Comment: how 'Object' class is able to use the methods of 'Class' class without inheriting or creating object.

Comment: Just look at your code ! You use the getClass() method which returns a Class instance. Simple as that.

Comment: @Sudheer It doesn't need to inherit them. It gets an instance of `Class` via the getClass method, and then it can call any accessible method of `Class` for that instance.

Comment: @Sudheer the `java.lang.Object` class defines a method `getClass` which returns the `java.lang.Class` object which is the runtime representation of the original object's class. The `getName` method belongs to the `Class` object, not to the original object itself.